# Как сделать аргументы через пробел Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно сделать команду для отправки сообщения в определенный канал. Но дело в том, что если записать сообщение с пробелом, то 2 часть сообщения будет относится к аргументу канала. То есть:

```
@bot.command()

async def send(ctx, message, * , channel: discord.TextChannel):

    await channel.send(message)
```

Если написать команду !send qq all #чат, то будет ошибка
`discord.ext.commands.errors.ChannelNotFound: Channel "all  <#90072344357037126>" not found.`

Как сделать так, чтобы пробел не означал конец аргумента?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите сохранить последовательность аргументов, то вам следует использовать команду так - `!send "my message" #channel`. В таком случае, всё что вы передаёте в кавычках будет считаться как аргумент `message`. Второй способ объяснил человек с ником RAINGM.

Answer (score 1):

У вас сама команда правильная, но вы в неправильном порядке расставили их.
Вы прописали их вот так:
`(ctx, message - одно сообщение до пробела, *, channel: discord.TextChannel - можно ввести как один канал, как и больше)`
Вы просто должны поменять местами аргументы в команде:
`(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, message)`
Надеюсь помог.

Comment: Звёздочка вам даёт преимущество много писать в **СОЕДУЩЕМ** аргументе, а не в стоящем перед нею.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, message,):
    await channel.send(message)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: не работает, ошибка discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'channel'

Comment: Как вы прописываете саму команду в discord?

Comment: `!send q q #чат`

Comment: Я вас понял, исправил функцию: `!send #chat q q`

Comment: Поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку, чтобы ответ был засчитан